Replacing Faucet- 1950s shelf sink

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove this faucet head. The handles were not an issue but I’m not sure what to do with this. There is no visible screw or mechanism to pop is off so I can thread the pieces through the back. I can’t find a similar model with instructions online. Any guidance would be appreciated :)

It would make sense that the spout unscrews from the front. I think you just need to use more force.

@RMDman and possibly some kind of penetrant.  Or maybe torching it to break any corrosion bond.  OP, have you tried a pipe/strap wrench on the round part next to the sink, with an adjustable wrench on the squarish section in the front?
